# What happens if I read a map's value where the key does not exist?

Tags: c++, dictionary

```
map<string, string> dada;
dada["dummy"] = "papy";
cout << dada["pootoo"];
```

I'm puzzled because I don't know if it's considered undefined behaviour or not, how to know when I request a key which does not exist, do I just use find instead ?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

The `map::operator[]` searches the data structure for a value corresponding to the given key, and returns a reference to it.

If it can't find one it transparently creates a default constructed element for it.  (If you do not want this behaviour you can use the `map::at` function instead.)

You can get a full list of methods of std::map here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

Here is the documentation of `map::operator[]` from the current C++ standard...

#### 23.4.4.3 Map Element Access

#### `T& operator[](const key_type& x);`

1. Effects: If there is no key equivalent to x in the map, inserts value_type(x, T()) into the map.
2. Requires: key_type shall be CopyConstructible and mapped_type shall be DefaultConstructible.
3. Returns: A reference to the mapped_type corresponding to x in *this.
4. Complexity: logarithmic.

#### `T& operator[](key_type&& x);`

1. Effects: If there is no key equivalent to x in the map, inserts value_type(std::move(x), T()) into the map.
2. Requires: mapped_type shall be DefaultConstructible.
3. Returns: A reference to the mapped_type corresponding to x in *this.
4. Complexity: logarithmic.

Comment: I actually did not find anywhere in the standard that it says that. At the very least, not at 23.3.1.2 [lib.map.access] or anywhere else that I could remember to check. EDIT: Apparently I was looking at an old version of the standard. My mistake.

Comment: @VladCiobanu: Above is 23.4.4.3 copied verbatim.  Are you using the current version `ISO/IEC 14882:2011(E)`?

Answer (score 34):

If you try to access a `key value` using index operator `[]`, then 2 things can happen :

1. The map contains this `key`. So it will return the corresponding `key value`.
2. The map doesn't contain the `key`. In this case, it will automatically add a `key` to the map with `null value`.

`"pootoo"` key does't exist in your map. So it will automatically add this `key` with `value = ""`(empty string). And your program will print empty string.

Here map size will increase by `1`.

To search a key you can use `map_name.find()`, which will return `map_name.end()` if the key doesn't exist. And no extra `key` will be added.

You can use `[]` operator when you want to set value for a key.

Answer (score 13):

It's not undefined behavior. If `operator []` doesn't find a value for the provided key, it inserts one at that position.

Comment: helpful. "it inserts one at that position." - it increases the size of map by 1 if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 8):

For operator[], if you try to access a value for a key that doesn't exist, a new value object that has been default constructed will be put into the map and it's reference returned.

Answer (score 3):

The `operator[]` for `map` returns a non-const reference and you can assign using that in the way you've shown on your second line. Accessing in this way will create a default contructed element of `value` type.

If you want to find a find an element, a better way is

```
iterator find ( const key_type& x )
```

(or the const alternative) which will return an iterator equal to `<map>.end()` if it doesn't find the key, or if you just want to know if it's in the collection you can use

```
size_type count ( const key_type& x ) const
```

which will always return either 1 or 0 for a map since keys are unique.

Answer (score 1):

If operator [] doesn't find a value for the provided key, it inserts one at that position.

But **you should note** that if you visit a `not exist key` and invoke it's member function, like mapKV[not_exist_key].member_fun().The program may crash.

**Let me give an example, test class as below:**

```
struct MapValue{
    int val;

    MapValue(int i=0){
        cout<<"ctor: "<<i<<endl; val = i;
    }

    ~MapValue(){
        cout<<"dtor: "<<val<<endl;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const MapValue& mv){
        cout<<"MapValue: "<<mv.val<<endl;
    }

    string toString(){
        cout<<"MapValue: "<<val<<endl;
    }
};
```

**Test code:**

```
cout<<"-------create map<int, MapValue>-------"<<endl;

map<int, MapValue> idName{{1, MapValue(1)}, {2, MapValue(2)}};

cout<<"-----cout key[2]-----"<<endl;
cout<<idName[2]<<endl;

cout<<"-----cout key[5]-----"<<endl;
cout<<idName[5]<<endl;

cout<<"------- runs here means, does't crash-------"<<endl;
```

**Output as below:**

```
-------create map<int, MapValue>-------
ctor: 1
ctor: 2
dtor: 2
dtor: 1
dtor: 2
dtor: 1
-----cout key[2]-----
MapValue: 2

-----cout key[5]-----
ctor: 0
MapValue: 0

-------runs here means, does't crash-------
dtor: 0
dtor: 2
dtor: 1
```

We can see that: `idName[5]` invoke map construct `{5, MapValue(0)}` to insert to idName.

**But if, you invoke member function by `idName[5]`, then the program crashes :**

```
cout<<"-------create map<int, MapValue>-------"<<endl;

map<int, MapValue> idName{{1, MapValue(1)}, {2, MapValue(2)}};


idName[5].toString();  // get crash here.


cout<<"------- runs here means, doesn't crash-------"<<endl;
```

Comment: it shouldn't crash because the map, must be some other mistake

Answer (score 0):

please have a look at the out_of_range exception:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/out_of_range/

this is what map::at and map::operator[] will throw if key does not exist. You can catch it the same way as the vector example in the link.

You can also use:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/

And check against map::end

Comment: no, only map::at throws, map::operator[] creates a new value_type if key doesn't exist